# Continuous assignment seemingly not working

Tags: vhdl

I'm working on a FIR filter, specifically the delay line. `x_delayed` is initialized to all zeros.

```
type slv32_array is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
...
signal x_delayed : slv32_array(0 to NTAPS-1) := (others => (others => '0'));
```

This does not work:

```
x_delayed(0) <= x;             -- Continuous assignment

DELAYS : process(samp_clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(samp_clk) then
        for i in 1 to NTAPS-1 loop
            x_delayed(i) <= x_delayed(i-1);
        end loop;
    end if; -- rising_edge(samp_clk)
end process;
```

[image: Simulation]

---

But this does:

```
DELAYS : process(samp_clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(samp_clk) then
        x_delayed(0) <= x;           -- Registering input
        for i in 1 to NTAPS-1 loop
            x_delayed(i) <= x_delayed(i-1);
        end loop;
    end if; -- rising_edge(samp_clk)
end process;
```

[image: Simulation]

The problem with this "solution" is that the first element in `x_delayed` is delayed by one sample, which it should *not* be. (The rest of the code expects `x_delayed(0)` to be the *current* sample).

I'm using Xilinx ISE 13.2, simulating with ISim, but this was also confirmed simulating with ModelSim.

What gives?

---

**Edit:**

The problem was essentially that, even though `x_delayed(0)` didn't appear to be driven inside the `process`, [it was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248941/119527).

After implementing [Brian Drummond's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/continuous-assignment-seemingly-not-working#comment26779546_18248941) it works perfectly:

```
x_delayed(0) <= x;

-- Synchronous delay cycles.
DELAYS : process(samp_clk)
begin
    -- Disable the clocked driver, allowing the continuous driver above to function correctly.
    -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/#comment26779546_18248941
    x_delayed(0) <= (others => 'Z');        

    if rising_edge(samp_clk) then
        for i in 1 to NTAPS-1 loop
            x_delayed(i) <= x_delayed(i-1);
        end loop;
    end if; -- rising_edge(samp_clk)
end process;
```

[image: Simulation]

---

**Edit 2:**

I took [OllieB's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/continuous-assignment-seemingly-not-working/18248401?noredirect=1#comment26794613_18248941) for getting rid of the `for` loop. I had to change it, since my `x_delayed` is indexed from `(0 to NTAPS-1)`, but we end up with this nice looking little process:

```
x_delayed(0) <= x;

DELAYS : process(samp_clk)
begin
    x_delayed(0) <= (others => 'Z');
    if rising_edge(samp_clk) then
        x_delayed(1 to x_delayed'high) <= x_delayed(0 to x_delayed'high-1);
    end if; -- rising_edge(samp_clk)
end process;
```

---

**Edit 3:**

Following [OllieB's next suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/continuous-assignment-seemingly-not-working/18248401?noredirect=1#comment26798001_18247955), it turns out the `x_delayed(0) <= (others => 'Z')` was unnecessary, following his previous change. The following works just fine:

```
x_delayed(0) <= x;

DELAYS : process(samp_clk)
begin    
    if rising_edge(samp_clk) then
        x_delayed(1 to x_delayed'high) <= x_delayed(0 to x_delayed'high-1);
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: x_delayed is a register bank (or so it seems). how do you intend on entering a value to a register without a process? by the way, didn't it give you some warning for using a std_logic_vector (x is std_logic_vector or integer? what's with all the negative values?) into a std_logic?

Comment: Could you specify the types for x and x_delayed please? from what you've pasted, it looks like you're assigning x(31 downto 0) to x_delayed(0). How is x defined?

Comment: Ah I see: x_delayed is an array of type x. The problem isn't immediately apparent from the code. Could you specify which tools you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to keep the question trimmed and I left a few important parts out.  Everything here is `std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)`.  I'm using Xilinx ISE.

Comment: The thought was that `x_delayed(0)` wouldn't be a register - it would simply be an "alias" for the `x` input. Maybe since it's part of the array, ISE doesn't realize that

Comment: I actually believe you could remove the x_delayed(0) <= (others => 'Z'); clause as x_delayed(1 to x_delayed'high) is a statically defined name. I might be wrong, and I don't have a copy of the standard to hand.

Comment: @OllieB You're right! I removed the `x_delayed(0) <= (others => 'Z');` and it still worked just fine. So what does this mean? MortenZdk's answer implies that there is an implicit driver for `x_delayed(0)` in the process. Why does removing the `for` loop, and replacing it with the single "shift" assignment" *not* try to assign  `'U'` to `x_delayed(0)` ?

Comment: Again, I don't have the standard to hand, but I believe it is because the shifted version of x_delayed is a locally static slice name, whereas the indexed version uses a variable as its index, so is not locally static.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first case, the `x_delayed(0)` actually has two drivers, out outside the
process, being `x_delayed(0) <= x`, and an implicit one inside the DELAY
process.

The driver inside the process is a consequence of a VHDL standard concept
called "longest static prefix", described in VHDL-2002 standard (IEEE Std
1076-2002) section "6.1 Names", and the loop construction with a loop variable
`i`, whereby the longest static prefix for `x_delayed(i)` is `x_delayed`.

The VHDL standard then further describes drives for processes in section
"12.6.1 Drivers", which says "... There is a single driver for a given scalar
signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal
assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static
prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S ...".

So as a (probably surprising) consequence the `x_delayed(0)` has a driver in
the DELAY process, which drives all std_logic elements to 'U' since unassigned,
whereby the std_logic resolution function causes the resulting value to be 'U',
no matter what value is driven by the external `x_delayed(0) <= x`.

But in the case of your code, there seems to be more to it, since there actually are some "0" values in the simulation output for `x_delayed(0)`, for what I can see from the figures.  However, it is hard to dig further into this when I do not have the entire code.

One way to see that the loop is the reason, is to manually roll out the loop by
replacing the `for ... loop` with:

```
x_delayed(1) <= x_delayed(1-1);
x_delayed(2) <= x_delayed(2-1);
...
x_delayed(NTAPS) <= x_delayed(NTAPS-1);
```

This is of course not a usable solution for configurable modules with NTAPS as
a generic, but it may be interesting to see that the operation then is as
intuitively expected.

**EDIT**: Multiple solutions are listed in "edit" sections after the question above, based on comments.  A solution with variable, which allows for complex expressions if required, is shown below.  If complex expression is not required, then as per [OllieB's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/continuous-assignment-seemingly-not-working/18248401?noredirect=1#comment26794613_18248941) it is possible to reduce the assign to `x_delayed(1 to x_delayed_dir'high) <= x_delayed(0 to x_delayed_dir'high-1)`:

```
x_delayed(0) <= x;
DELAYS : process(samp_clk)
  variable x_delayed_v : slv32_array(1 to NTAPS-1);
begin
  if rising_edge(samp_clk) then
    for i in 1 to NTAPS-1 loop
      x_delayed_v(i) := x_delayed(i-1);  -- More complex operations are also possible
    end loop;
    x_delayed(1 to x_delayed_dir'high) <= x_delayed_v;
  end if;  -- rising_edge(samp_clk)
end process;
```

Comment: Another approach is to turn OFF the clocked process driver with `x_delayed(0) <= 'Z';` inside the process, so that the external continuous driven value resolves correctly. Bit of a bodge but it ought to work...

Comment: @Brian Drummond: Do you think synthesis tools will handle that correctly ?

Comment: Fairly sure XST would figure it out; Synplicity may not. It may also depend on the tool version; they keep changing; usually for the better. Only one way to find out for certain...

Comment: Yes, that was surprising to know that `x_delayed(0)` is being driven inside the process! I noticed this in another instance as well, and was very confused. You spelled it out very informatively, thank you! I'm surprised that XST didn't complain about multiple drivers though.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I ended up going with your idea (`(others => 'Z')`, b/c it's an array), and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much guys, this all makes sense to me know that I realize that subtle detail.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Is it possible to use x_delayed(x_delayed'high downto 1) <= x_delayed(x_delayed'high-1 downto 0); as this is a statically defined name?

Comment: @OllieB That compiled, but ISim crashed with "ERROR: at 0 ps: Signal x_delayed index is out of bound."

Comment: @OllieB I got it to work :-) My array is indexed `(0 to NTAPS-1)` so I had to change what you had to `x_delayed(1 to x_delayed'high) <= x_delayed(0 to x_delayed'high-1);`  See my **Edit 2**.

Comment: This can be much simpler.   Concatenation `&` is supported for all single dimensional arrays.   Remove the 0 index from the array.   Do the shifting by: `x_delayed <= x & x_delayed(1 to NTAPS-2)`

Answer (score 1):

During elaboration, drivers are created for all elements in x_delayed, regardless of the range of loop iterator. Hence, x_delayed(0) has two drivers associated with it. Std_Logic and Std_Logic_Vector are resoved types(i.e., when multiple drivers are associated with the signal with these types, the resolved function will determine the value of the signal by looking up a table in std package. Please refer to *VHDL Coding Styles and Methodologies* for more details.

Comment: "drivers are created for all elements in x_delayed, regardless of the range of loop iterator" - Indeed! I did not realize this.

Answer (score 0):

the reason you have a problem is that the logic thinks you have two things assigning into the same signal simultaneously - both the continues assignment and the register assignment loop. 
keep with the register implementation.

*edit*
if you have modelsim, you can use the 'trace x' option and see where it comes from.
might be that the other simulator also have this feature, but for modelsim i'm certain it works

Comment: I don't see two things assigning the same signal anywhere. The loop is assigning to 1 to NTAPS-1, while 0 is assigned from the `x` input.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you. But now that others have explained it in a bit more detail, I see that you were correct, and `x_delayed(0)` *does* in fact, have two drivers. I've upvoted you to compensate :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks :).   to be honest we had a very similar problem at work a couple of hours after i answered you, and i immediately thought of this question but eventually it turned out to be the QC testbench that pushed all them 'X's :)

Answer (score -2):

In you not working example
    x_delayed(0) <= x;

is aquvalent to

```
process(x)
begin
   x_delayed(0) <= x;
end process;
```

So the process will assign x_delayed(0) only when x changes. Because this is a signal asignment the x_delayed(0) will not change immediatly, it will change after a delta cycle. Therefore, when process DELAYS is called assignment for x_delayed(0) is not happened yet!

Use a variable for x_delayed in your process, if you could.

```
x_delayed(0) := x;
```

Comment: Even with a delta delay from `x` to `x_delayed(0)`, the `x_delayed(0)` should not be undefined, so this explanation does not sound correct.