# Vhdl generic fulladder code

Tags: vhdl, fpga

here is a generic code of a cascade full adder.

the problem is that the result of the fulladder appears with one event delay(I mean that when I change inputs1 & inputs2 the result of the previous inputs appears). I know that if I write the code without a process this delay wouldn't occur but I need to write a generic fulladder and there is no way to write a generic code without a process and a for loop.

so I'm asking if anyone could help me to fix the code so that the output would show the results with no delay!!!

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity adders is
    generic(
        numberOfInputs : Integer := 4
    ); port(
        enable  : in std_logic;
        cin     : in std_logic;
        inputs1 : in std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);
        inputs2 : in std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);
        outputs : out std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs downto 0)
    );
end entity adders;

architecture Generic_Adder of adders is
    signal Couts:std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs downto 0);
    signal temp1:std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);
    signal temp2:std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);
    signal temp3:std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);

begin

    temp2<=inputs1;
    temp3<=inputs2;  
    couts(0)<= cin;

    Sum:process(temp2,temp3,cin,enable,Couts) is
    begin
        for count in 0 to numberOfInputs-1 loop
            temp1(count) <= (temp2(count) xor temp3(count));
            outputs(count) <= Couts(count) xor temp1(count);
            Couts(count+1) <= (temp2(count) and temp3(count)) or(couts(count) and temp1(count));--cout(count) is the previuos cout becuase the first cout is cin
        end loop;
    end process;

    outputs(numberOfInputs) <= Couts(numberOfInputs);
end Generic_Adder;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `temp1` signal is used in the process, but it is missing in the sensitivity list.

Changes in `temp1` will therefore not trigger reevaluation of the process, and the a new value of `temp1` is not reflected in other driven signals until another signal trigger reevaluation, hence you are likely to experience a "delay".

Fix this by adding `temp1` to the sensitivity list, or rewrite as suggested by Bill Lynch or if you are using VHDL-2008 and compatible compiler, then the sensitivity list can be `process (all) ...`.

In addition, a VHDL issue related to "longest static prefix" is encountered due to the drive of `outputs` by loop in the process and `outputs(numberOfInputs)` outside the process.  The result is that `outputs(numberOfInputs)` has a driver as `'U'` from the process and a driver as `Couts(numberOfInputs)` outside the process.  The resulting value, based on the `std_logic` resolution function, is a value of ´'U'´.

One way to fix this issue, when keeping the process, is to move the `outputs(numberOfInputs)` inside the process, like:

```
        ...
    end loop;
    outputs(numberOfInputs) <= Couts(numberOfInputs);
end process;
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248941/2352082 has more information about VHDL longest static prefix.

Comment: or if they are using a new enough compiler: `process (all)`. Additionally `cin` and `enable` are not needed in the sensitivity list. And I'm not sure how they are going to write this without a latch if they want to actually use the `enable` bit and have the output be held.

Comment: You can also have `temp1` be a variable instead of a signal. In that case, it doesn't have to be a vector, in simple std_logic would be fine.

Comment: the was no delay in the output but the outputs(1) and outputs(2) are unknown(u)!!??how do I fix that??

Comment: If `outputs(1)` or `outputs(2)` are unknown `'X'` it is probably due to unknown `'X'` input data.  But the MSB `outputs(4)` will actually become unknown `'X'` due to an VHDL issue called "longest static prefix"; please see update in the answer.

Comment: Btw. the carry generation by `Couts` looks wrong; see Bill Lynch answer for carry generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generate statement to write iterative code outside of a process statement. It would probably look something like this:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity adders is
    generic(
        numberOfInputs : Integer := 4
    ); port(
        enable  : in std_logic;
        cin     : in std_logic;
        inputs1 : in std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);
        inputs2 : in std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs-1 downto 0);
        outputs : out std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs downto 0)
    );
end entity adders;

architecture Generic_Adder of adders is
    signal carry  : std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs     downto 0);
    signal result : std_logic_vector(numberOfInputs - 1 downto 0);
begin

    carry(0) <= cin;

    for I in 0 to numberOfInputs-1 generate
    begin
        result(I) <= inputs1(I) xor inputs2(I) xor carry(I);
        carry(I+1) <= 
            (inputs1(I) and inputs2(I)) or 
            (inputs1(I) and carry(I))   or
            (inputs2(I) and carry(I));
    end generate;

    outputs <= carry(numberOfInputs) & result;

end Generic_Adder;
```

Comment: @BillLynch: In `result(I)` the `+` should be `xor`.