# VHDL issue with process loop variables and arrays

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I have an array of std_logic_vectors in which I want to implement a delay chain. I wrote it up like this, and it works fine:

```
   --Signal Declaration
   type MyArrayType is array(0 to 3) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   signal s_aslv_DelayChain : MyArrayType;

   --Concurrent Statement, Load input chain
   s_aslv_DelayChain(0) <= ip_slv_Input;

   --Delay line Process
   DelayProc : process(ip_sl_Clk)
   begin
     if(rising_edge(ip_sl_Clk)) then

       s_aslv_DelayChain(1) <= s_aslv_DelayChain(0);
       s_aslv_DelayChain(2) <= s_aslv_DelayChain(1);
       s_aslv_DelayChain(3) <= s_aslv_DelayChain(2);

     end if; --rising_edge(ip_sl_Clk)
   end process DelayProc;
```

This produces the result I would expect:

[image]

However, if I change the process to use  a looping variable:

```
   --Delay line Process
   DelayProc : process(ip_sl_Clk)
   begin
     if(rising_edge(ip_sl_Clk)) then    
       for n in 1 to 3 loop
         s_aslv_DelayChain(n) <= s_aslv_DelayChain(n-1);
       end loop;
     end if; --rising_edge(ip_sl_Clk)
   end process DelayProc;
```

It doesn't work and I get a bunch of U's:

[image]

Shouldn't the 2 coding styles describe the same behavior?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you didn't delete the assignment to the first member of the delay chain, you have run into the "longest static prefix" rule which requires the second process to drive all of `...DelayChain` ... i.e. including `...DelayChain(0).` Which creates 2 drivers on that signal, resolving as `'U'`. Given that information you'll find ways of bringing that assignment into the process too.

Comment: Thanks! I moved the (0) assignment into the process and now it works fine. It still baffles me why the first style worked, since the (0) assignment was still outside the process.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Don't you mean "no?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I mean the two *styles* should describe teh same behaviour. The practical details of the second require some refinement to get there, with several choices how.

Comment: @BrianDrummond your comment was the first place on the internet where I read that that this was a language issue and not a simulator problem (after that leading me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/continuous-assignment-seemingly-not-working). Would you consider writing an answer to make it easy to find for others? Currently search terms such as vhdl loop multiple drivers, element zero also driven, etc. don't lead people to answers quickly.

Comment: Can you post your own solution as an answer? That way we can close of this question.