# VHDL ignores statement outside a process

Tags: vhdl

I hope this is in the right place, but since I think it's an issue with syntax instead of actual system design maybe it is.

For some reason I have a statement that is ignored when I leave it outside a process. I can copy/paste the same statement into a process and suddenly it works. But then it has to wait on the clock signal, which messes up the whole thing.

```
architecture CU of CONTROL_UNIT is
    type OPCODE_ARRAY is array(3 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal OPCODES : OPCODE_ARRAY;
begin
    OPCODES(3) <= OPCODE_IN; --problem statement!
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            for I in 0 to 2 loop
                OPCODES(I) <= OPCODES(I + 1);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end process;
    --more code
end CU;
```

If I simulate it like this, I get this situation that I don't understand:

[image: Notice OPCODE_IN is D but OPCODE(3) is still U]

Notice OPCODE_IN is D but OPCODES(3) is still U.

If I move the statement inside the process, it will shift the value of OPCODE_IN into OPCODES(3) but of course it takes another clock cycle which messes up the timing of everything:

```
architecture CU of CONTROL_UNIT is
    type OPCODE_ARRAY is array(3 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal OPCODES : OPCODE_ARRAY;
begin
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            for I in 0 to 2 loop
                OPCODES(I) <= OPCODES(I + 1);
            end loop;
            OPCODES(3) <= OPCODE_IN; --problem statement!
        end if;
    end process;
    --more code
end CU;
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this is behaving this way?

Comment: Useful search term : "longest static prefix" +VHDL

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers
*Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of drivers for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement.* The longest static prefix is OPCODES which has 4 elements. See 8. Names, 8.1 General, the last paragraph, I is a variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvhdl%5D+longest+static+prefix You'd be better off asking how to fix it, there's likely to be an applicable question with an answer your question would be a duplicate of.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955/continuous-assignment-seemingly-not-working/18248941#18248941

Comment: It looks like unrolling the loop resolved it. I don't think I quite understand why though. Is it just because OPCODES(3) is referenced in it?

Comment: 8.1 *...The longest static prefix of a signal name is the name itself, if the name is a static signal name; otherwise, it is the longest prefix of the name that is a static signal name. ...* The longest static prefix in the process is OPCODES. OPCODES(I) (8.4 Indexed names) isn't a static expression (9.4) and the process drives all elements. Resolution (4.6 Resolution functions, 14.7.3.2 Driving values) of the two drivers will be 'U' (the driver in the process has an initial value 'U' for OPCODES(3)).  Static names (e.g. `OPCODES(2)`) have a longer longest static prefix.

Comment: Could you please add a test bench next time? Now I have to write one to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up answers in the comments:

Process from your first example will create drivers for all signals from the longest static prefix of OPCODES(I), which is OPCODES. So OPCODES(0) will have driver too. But in your process there is no assignment for OPCODES(0), hence it is 'U'.

When you put `OPCODES(3) <= OPCODE_IN;` in the process, you make assignment, and problem is solved.

When you unroll your loop, the longest static prefix for your assignments, becomes `OPCODES(1)`, `OPCODES(2)`, and `OPCODES(3)`, instead of `OPCODES`. So you don't have driver for `OPCODES(0)` any more, and problem is solved again.

Comment: Oh, I see, so that's what static prefix means. Static as in is the same for each case represented in the loop. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can express the shift directly and eliminate both the `for...loop` and the longest static prefix issue.

```
process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        OPCODES <= OPCODE_IN & OPCODES(3 downto 1);
    end if;
end process;
```

Or, if you have a preference for the loop ...

```
architecture CU of CONTROL_UNIT is
    type OPCODE_ARRAY is array(3 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal OPCODES : OPCODE_ARRAY;
begin
    process(CLK, OPCODE_IN)
    begin
        OPCODES(3) <= OPCODE_IN;
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            for I in 0 to 2 loop
                OPCODES(I) <= OPCODES(I + 1);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end process;
    --more code
end CU;
```

...though I do not find it very satisfying. The assignment to `OPCODES(3)` does not have to be inside the clocked portion of the process.

It has an ugliness to it as it requires the extra signal in the sensitivity list and it does not offer any obvious reason for its inclusion as a solution to the static prefix problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the quirks where VHDL becomes very counter-intuitive. It is especially confusing since other parallel processing languages don't have it.

Another solution would be to use generate-statement.

```
architecture CU of CONTROL_UNIT is
    type OPCODE_ARRAY is array(3 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal OPCODES : OPCODE_ARRAY;
begin
    OPCODES(3) <= OPCODE_IN; --problem statement!
    some_label: for I in 0 to 2 generate
        OPCODES(I) <= OPCODES(I + 1) when rising_edge(clk);
    end generate;
    --more code
end architecture;
```

Funny enough, in this case `OPCODES(I)` suddenly is a static expression again. Very consistent, eh? ;)

Comment: Each block statement elaborated from  the generate statement  will have a constant I declared with the Iterated value (IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.8, *...The generate parameter is a constant object...*, 14.5.3). Concurrent assignment elaborates into a process (11.3) with a driver for OPCODES(I + 1) for it's assignment (14.7.2). The longest static prefix (8.1) includes the index (I + 1) which is  a globally static expression (9.4.2 s). The loop statement specification dynamically declares a variable not assigned in it's sequence of statements (10.10, 14.6 a). Apples and oranges. ;)

Comment: @user1155120 True, but these kind of things make the language difficult to learn. It's like my own language Dutch, which is considered [difficult to learn](http://www.learndutch.org/beginners/is-dutch-hard-to-learn/). It's Germanic-based, like English. In its basis the language has the same relatively simple grammar. However, there are many exceptions to the general cases. Even the native speakers are often confused: every year we have a Dutch dictation competition broadcaster on national TV, and the past years it was not won by a Dutchman ;) Same for VHDL: even the experts are often confused.

Comment: The -1987 standard has about 60 percent text in common with  the Ada83 LRM, sections rearranged, simulation and hardware description (e.g. generate statements) heavily influenced by CONLAN*  added creating a different language. Its usage requiring understanding and not amenable to being approached or used as a programming language. See *VHDL for Simulation, Synthesis and Formal Proofs of Hardware*,  1992, 2nd ed 1995, Kluwer Academic Publishers, ISBN 978-1-4613-6582-2 and *Fundamentals and Standards in Hardware Description Languages*, 1992,  also Kluwer, DOI 10.1007/978-94-011-1914-6